# how can I find and replace using xpath and limit my scope using intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, xpath

I want to find and replace a dependency in a multi-module project in IntelliJ 2017.3.

I *did* find how to limit the scope of the search by creating a new `scope` and setting the pattern to `file[*]:pom.xml`.

Since the search is specific, I *could* search for the entire `<dependency>...</dependency>` string, but the latest search doesn't make multi-line find-and-replace very legible.

What I would like to do is use an `xpath` search for `/project/dependencies/dependency[./artifactId[text()='mymodule']` and insert a new node `<type>war</type>`.  Is there a way to do this?

My `find by xpath` doesn't seem to net me any results, and I don't know how to do an insert if it did.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is missing the last `]` to close out your predicate:

```
/project/dependencies/dependency[./artifactId[text()='mymodule']]
```

You could more simply write that as:

```
/project/dependencies/dependency[artifactId='mymodule']
```

I don't believe that there is a "replace by XPath", only ["search by XPath"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/xpath-search.html).

If you used [find and replace by regex](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html), you could search for:

```
(<artifactId>[\n\s]*mymodule[\n\s]*</artifactId>)
```

and replace with:

```
$1\n<type>war</type>
```

Comment: Thanks, my XPath is a little rusty.  The problem with the `regex` though is it doesn't constrain the search to *only when it appears in `dependencies`*.  I'd have to include some elaborate look behind; this is where XSLT is more powerful.